# I want to create a spinner inside the recyclerView in android kotlin and when in enter the ArrayAdapter the error is showing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I want to create a **spinner** inside the `recyclerView` in android kotlin and when in enter the `ArrayAdapter` the error is showing

```
class CoustomAdapter(val userList: ArrayList<ModelDataClass>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CoustomAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(p0?.context).inflate(R.layout.green_red_list, p0, false)
        return  ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
        val user : ModelDataClass = userList[p1]
        p0?.textViewName?.text = user.name
        p0?.textViewAddress?.text = user.address
        val name = arrayOf("Arka","Ram", "Rahul", "Romen")
// In this next line when i initialize the ArrayAdapter the show a error
        val spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this@CoustomAdapter, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, name)
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewRecourse(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line)
        p0.spinner.adapter = spinnerAdapter
        p0.spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, Id: Long) {

            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }
        }
    }
    class ViewHolder(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
            val textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name) as TextView
            val textViewAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Address) as TextView
            val spinner  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dropdown) as Spinner
        }
    }
```

Comment: why do you need a spinner inside a recyclerview?

Comment: Can you post error message here?